# Pass data from form submit to controller via get Method

Tags: laravel, routes

can anyone tell, what is wrong with the following way to pass the data from view->route->controller. Currently I get  Missing required parameters for [Route: `show.exclusion`] [URI: `exclusion/create/{id}`]

This is my view part:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">In welcher Gruppe möchten Sie User einladen?</div>
            <div class="panel-body"> 
            {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'show.exclusion', 'method'=>'get', 'id'=>'$group->idgroup')) !!}  
                <div class="form-group">  
                    {{Form::label('choosegroup', 'Wähle eine Gruppe')}}
                    <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="idgroup">
                        @foreach($groups as $group)
                            <option id="{{ $group->idgroup }}">{{ $group->groupname }}</option>    
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                        <!--{{ csrf_field() }}-->
                </div>
                <div>
                    {{Form::submit('Search',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-close" href="{{ route('home') }}">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!} 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my route...

```
Route::get('exclusion/create/{id}', 'ExclusionController@show')->name('show.exclusion');
```

And here you can see my controller function...

```
public function show($id)
{   
    $groupid = $id;
    $members = V_Exclusion::where([['idgroup', $groupid],['groupadmin', Auth::id()]])->get();
    $groups  = V_Exclusion::where('groupadmin', Auth::id())->get();

    return view('exclusions.createexclusion')
           ->with('members', $members)
           ->with('groups', $groups);
}
```

Comment: Your method on a form should `POST` and you need to uncomment the `csrf_field()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

In Route

```
Route::get('exclusion/create/{id}', 'ExclusionController@show');

{!! Form::open(array('route'=>['exclusion/create',$group->idgroup], 'method'=>'get', 'id'=>'$group->idgroup')) !!}
```